# The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: dart

I trying to retrieve my data from API server and present it in my mobile application using flutter .. but i got error

> The getter 'length' was called on null

Any advice plz ... thanks

my code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:json/add.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Future<List> getData() async {
  String url = 'http://192.168.0.55:4000/api/contacts';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/Add': (BuildContext context) => new Add(),
      },
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;

  void getList() async {
    this.data = (await getData());
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getList();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: new Text("Chat"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text('${data[position]['name']}'),
              );
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.person_add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Add');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Output Console

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 4,410ms.
I/flutter (10119): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (10119): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: HomePageState#80635):
I/flutter (10119): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (10119): Receiver: null
I/flutter (10119): Tried calling: length
I/flutter (10119): 
I/flutter (10119): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (10119): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (10119): #1      HomePageState.build (package:json/main.dart:59:29)
I/flutter (10119): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27)
I/flutter (10119): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
I/flutter (10119): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #33     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #34     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #40     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #41     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #46     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #47     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #48     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #49     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #51     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #52     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #54     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #56     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #57     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #58     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #60     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #61     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #63     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #64     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #65     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #66     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #67     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #68     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #70     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #72     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #73     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #74     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #76     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #77     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #79     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #80     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #81     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #82     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #83     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #84     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #85     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #86     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #87     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #88     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #89     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #90     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #91     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #92     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #93     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #94     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #95     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #96     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #97     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #98     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4965:32)
I/flutter (10119): #99     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #101    _TheatreElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:493:16)
I/flutter (10119): #102    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #106    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #107    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #108    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #109    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #110    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #111    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #112    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #113    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #114    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #115    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #117    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #118    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #119    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #120    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #121    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #122    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #123    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #124    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #125    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #126    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #127    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #128    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #163    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #164    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #165    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #166    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #167    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #168    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #169    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #170    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #171    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #172    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #173    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #174    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #175    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #176    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #177    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #178    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #179    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter (10119): #180    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #181    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #182    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #183    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #184    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #185    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #186    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #187    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #202    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #203    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #204    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #205    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #206    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #207    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #208    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #209    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #210    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #211    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #212    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #213    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #214    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #215    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #216    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #217    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #218    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #219    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #220    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #221    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #222    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #223    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #224    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #225    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #226    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #227    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #228    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #229    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #230    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #231    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #232    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #233    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #234    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #235    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #236    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter (10119): #237    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #238    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #239    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #240    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter (10119): #241    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter (10119): #242    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter (10119): #243    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter (10119): #244    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter (10119): #245    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter (10119): #246    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:909:16)
I/flutter (10119): #247    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:880:5)
I/flutter (10119): #248    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:826:17)
I/flutter (10119): #249    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2266:19)
I/flutter (10119): #250    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:825:13)
I/flutter (10119): #251    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:712:7)
I/flutter (10119): #252    runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:756:7)
I/flutter (10119): #253    main (package:json/main.dart:8:16)
I/flutter (10119): #254    _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:289:19)
I/flutter (10119): #255    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (10119): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (10119): [{_id: 5c55e837b1dee7326c4ba39d, create_date: 2019-02-02T18:57:59.406Z, name: Tariq, gender: male, email: ta@gmail.com, phone: 07954622145, __v: 0}, {_id: 5c55e86cb1dee7326c4ba39e, create_date: 2019-02-02T18:58:52.346Z, name: He, gender: Female, email: h@gmail.com, phone: 075554622145, __v: 0}, {_id: 5c55e890b1dee7326c4ba39f, create_date: 2019-02-02T18:59:28.108Z, name: Sh, gender: Female, email: sh@gmail.com, phone: 075654622145, __v: 0}, {_id: 5c584f60af32d00dec0facae, create_date: 2019-02-04T14:42:40.036Z, name: Emad, gender: male, email: emad@gmail.com, __v: 0}, {_id: 5c585236af32d00dec0facaf, create_date: 2019-02-04T14:54:46.734Z, name: Fa, gender: Female, email: Fa@gmail.com, phone: 075654622145, __v: 0}, {_id: 5c58605bcf4f4c3008e50a04, create_date: 2019-02-04T15:55:07.696Z, name: Fa, gender: Female, email: f @gmail.com, phone: 075654622145, __v: 0}]
```

when i run the code i got the data in the console, but the UI for mobile APP . i get the error 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3SNP.png)

Answer (score 11):

You need to guard against the case when `data == null`

```
  body: new Center(
    child: data == null ? Container() : new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text('${data[position]['name']}'),
          );
        }),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind is **If you are using a List and trying to get it's length while the list is null**.
In order to remove the exception is to initialize the **List data** (in the above code) with some values (Before getting the required values).
What I did was just initialized the list with an empty array. like,

```
List _elements = [];
```

Comments please.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by ABHIMANGAL MS was perfect for me.
We made a list data at the top of our page like:

```
list data;
```

This was null obv. We then ran json under it to get our data from an api and populate data with that info.
However the page would first load data while empty then make the api call.

Making data: `list data = [];` removed the error it would throw up for a second before loading the json data. so thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

For my own future reference when receiving this error during http POST requests, Flutter doesn't like sending `null` values in the body of the request. I was working with an API call that had a `null` requirement in the request - I simply ignored this and only sent the parameters that were non-null